# How to escape square brackets inside brackets in grep

Tags: regex, grep, escaping, regex-negation

I want to match the other than square brackets characters in regular expression.

Precisely I want to match some special characters and some others don't, thus I want to specify them

```
# grep $'[^a-zA-Z0-9#\\/:!<>{},=?. ()["_+;*\'&|$-]' file
```

This is missing a `]`, I have tried escaping with `\]`, `\\]` and so on, I read people doing that outer the `[^]`, but I need it inside!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the `]` immediately after the `^`.

Here's an example. Input file "foo" contains:

```
foo
[
bar
]
baz
quux
```

We execute the command:

```
grep '[^][]' foo
```

The output is:

```
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

From the documentation on [bracket expressions in POSIX regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05):

> The right-bracket ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list (after an initial circumflex ( '^' ), if any).

and also:

> The special characters '.', '*', '[', and '\' (period, asterisk, left-bracket, and backslash, respectively) shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression.

Comment: Your expression is correct, but your explanation isn't. Most implementations of regexes do not recognize the `\\` as an escape-character in sets, so you have to put the `]` somewhere where it isn't part of the syntax - directly behind the `[` or the `[^`.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm You are correct. It's funny how my fingers knew what to do better than my brain at that moment. I have corrected the explanation.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but why need to be this way? There is a specification?

Comment: @TiagoPimenta I've added a link to and some excerpts from the relevant documentation.